# Odd Even Numbers Using Switch without user input

Tags: java, switch-statement, modulus

Initialize two integer variables and set them to zero.  loop through each item in the array and do a calculation to determine if the number is even or odd (using the modulus operator). Using a switch statement, increment one variable for all even numbers and do the same for the other variable for any odd numbers (using the increment operator).
Output the total number of even and off numbers to the screen.

**Example output:**

```
34, 53, 125, 854 8, 1045, 66, 9434, 5205, 235
There are 5 even numbers.
There are 5 odd numbers.
```

Here is my code

```
public class Switch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int n = 0;
        int e = 0, o = 0;

         for( n = 5; n < 50; n++)

         {

            if(n % 2 == 0)
                     System.out.println(n);


       //e= 0; o = 0;

          switch(n){
                case 1: o = 0;
                case 3:
                case 5:
                case 7:
                case 9: o++; break;
                // these are Even
                case 2: e = 0;
                case 4:
                case 6:
                case 8:
                case 10: e++; break;

                default: System.out.println("no odd or even numbers");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You have " + e + " even numbers:  and you have odd numbers " + o);
    }
}
```

Here is my out put what am I doing wrong.

```
no odd or even numbers
48
no odd or even numbers
no odd or even numbers
You have 3 even numbers:  and you have odd numbers 3
```

Comment: You are switching on `n` instead of `n % 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your original code is the `switch(n)` statement. This is (roughly) equivalent of saying

```
if (n == 1) {
    o = 0;
} else if (n == 2) {
    e = 0;
}
if (n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7 || n == 9) {
    o++;
}
else if (n == 4 || n == 6 || n == 8 || n == 10) {
    e++;
}
else {
    System.out.println("no odd or even numbers");
}
```

I trust you can see what is wrong with that code and I hope it explains your initial output.

You loop on the range of 5 to 50, and so your 3 even numbers are 6, 8, and 10, and your 3 odd numbers are 5, 7, and 9. All even numbers were printed and the rest were printed as `no odd or even numbers`.

---

Here is a working solution based upon your question.

Notice that there are only 2 states for a number, even or odd (`0` or `1`). Therefore your print statement for "No even or odd number" does not make sense.

I am also unsure what you were doing with that loop from 5 to 50...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] nums = new int[] {34, 53, 125, 854, 8, 1045, 66, 9434, 5205, 235};

        int e = 0, o = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        {
            int remainder = nums[i] % 2;

            switch(remainder){
                case 0:
                    e++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    o++;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + e + " even numbers. There are " + o + " odd numbers.");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I did not see that I was switching on the (n) I am new to all of this I can take it from here.

Comment: @Smood - Glad I could help. You can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark by the up-down votes if you wish.